# Understanding suitcases characteristics

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I am very confused with buying a new suitcase for my flights, planned to be my 23kg luggage that goes in cargo, thus I am asking for your experience please (this is not a question for personal opinion, so I believe it's okay to ask).

I am comparing two suitcases of same price, one 78cm and the other 74cm (typical for [checked-in luggage](https://www.mybaggage.com/shipping/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Air_France_Baggage_Allowance.jpg)), but the 74cm has greater H x L x W characteristics, which seems like a paradox to me, so I am afraid I have misunderstood something.

The [78cm](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07HMF7BQ8/ref=sr_1_9?crid=3EISX08KCOM35&keywords=amazonbasics%2Bkoffer&qid=1574007238&sprefix=amazonbasics%2Bsu%2Caps%2C237&sr=8-9&th=1&fbclid=IwAR1aXo_nFN49GCI1p3CdYNzPJpDysYK84AvSMUqqyqLJYb5jS631Fom-Xkk):
[image]

The [74cm](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B071L7V8YH/ref=sxin_5_pb?crid=3EISX08KCOM35&keywords=amazonbasics%2Bkoffer&pd_rd_i=B071L7V8YH&pd_rd_r=d6a979dc-dd0a-4361-921c-e6fd9b91cfd7&pd_rd_w=BJ6aD&pd_rd_wg=sgkQi&pf_rd_p=50605237-bbe1-41d1-8cfd-049ff07200b3&pf_rd_r=ZTXVC2SV3KEEY5EK4GJR&qid=1574007238&sprefix=amazonbasics%2Bsu%2Caps%2C237&th=1&fbclid=IwAR3LmaEjRWdPB8L3drLPo0aXoH4MMTg3WNEVEUw7-PkB7XSM3GwugZI6OwI):
[image]

As you can see, the 74cm (the smaller one) has 78.5 x 44.5 x 33, while the 78cm (which is larger I think) has 78.5 x 44.5 x 32.8.

I was ready to compare them by their weight and select the lighter one, but now I am so confused, can you please help clear the smog?

Comment: some manufacturers count the wheels when they name the size, some don't. Of course, for the airline it doesn't matter, the overall size including all pieces count.

Comment: @Aganju both suitcases are from the same manufacturer in this case though, i.e. AmazonBasics.

Comment: Those pictures came through very blurry.  **The ruling factor on luggage is quality**.  It's all fine and good to save money, until you're going through the airport and suddenly a caster breaks off.  Now you're in a pickle, because you must awkwardly drag around this dead weight for the rest of the trip.  I've had mixed luck with Amazon Basics; I realize the Amazon brand has a lot of [halo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect) for you, but having a logistics and fulfillment empire doesn't make them good at luggage.

Comment: I guess I'll find out @Harper-ReinstateMonica, thanks for the warning! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a simple "translation" issue.

If you look at these two products on the US Amazon site, both are shown as a "30 inch" model, and both have their external dimensions listed as "17.5 x 12.9 x 30.9 Inches".

"17.5 x 12.9 x 30.9 Inches" converted to centimeters is "44.5 x 32.8 x 78.5" which matches exactly the size shown on the pages you've linked to (with the 32.8 rounded to 33 which is only a difference of 2mm).

Thus it seems most likely that when translating this products page from English to German they simply incorrectly entered the size of the "74cm" model, and it should actually be stated as "78cm" as per the second suitcase.  One way or another, both bags are the same size (and based on the photos, appear to be exactly the same bag only in a different fabric!)

Comment: Oh dear, I didn't think of that, damn! Thanks Doc, you answered my question, here is the [1st](https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Belltown-Softside-Luggage-Suitcase/dp/B07HMF7BQ8/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=AmazonBasics%2BBelltown&qid=1574016056&sr=8-1&th=1) and the [2nd](https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Softside-Spinner-Luggage-Suitcase/dp/B071L7V8YH/ref=sr_1_12?dchild=1&keywords=amazon%2Bbasics%2Bluggage&qid=1574015938&sr=8-12&th=1). I am now wondering which one to choose, what do you personally think? Since they are the same pretty much, simply go for the lighter one?

Comment: Judging from the links provided in your comment, the bags seem very similar, apart from colour. One is supposed to be 7.87 lb and the other 7.91 lb, which would be a difference of 18 g. This could just be a question of using different conversion factors.

Comment: Wow, if I bought them (from Italy) I'd have to pay 407.12$ for "shipping and import fees". Ouch!

Comment: But @Arne both are from the same manufacturer (AmazonBasics), so I would expect to have the same conversion factor.. Right?

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica if I buy them from Amazon.com, then yeah, but if I purchase them from Amazon.de, then it's all good (and I have Prime, so no shipping costs)! :)